# I still have the Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl after making all the necessary changes

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is a known one on this site.

Angular Material 16.0.0

I am having that error, however, I tried all the solutions available at this site and the official documentation, and still got the error.

1. Added **MatInputModule** and **MatFormFieldModule** to the module:

```
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
    import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
    import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field'
    import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
    
    const modules = [
        MatCardModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: modules,
        exports: modules
    })
    export class MaterialModule {}
```

This is imported and exported by app.modules

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialModule,
   ...
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2. Added **matInput** to the input element and the input closes with a "/" and with no *ngIf condition

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">
   <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>User Name</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="User Name" formControlName="username" />
      </mat-form-field>
   </p>
...
</form>
```

3. Made the form on the component side and even **included the providers** to it

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [
        { provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: LoginComponent }
    ]
})
export class LoginComponent {
    loginForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        username: new FormControl(''),
        password: new FormControl(''),
    })

...
// rest of the code
```

This is frustating because this is even borrowed from another code that I made and that works.

The only thing I did different was install Angular Material as the new documentation says, with **ng add @angular/material** command, which didn't help that much as I had to manually install it anyway...

What could be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well...

I forgot to delete this dude at the end of the form...

```
<p>
  <mat-form-field></mat-form-field>
</p>
```

But I was getting 2 errors, so I though it had to do with my other 2 inputs.

Anyway... Hope this helps someone